# Sets A and C with m-1 Elements

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

If A is a set with m elements and C is a set with one element, then A-C is a set with m-1 elements. What is a proof for this statement?

Comment: Not always true what you want to prove. If the element of C also belong in A, then indeed A-C has m-1 elements. But if the element of C is different from all elements of A, then A-C still has m elements.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence of the question is true only if $C \subseteq A$. If the sets are disjoint then $A \smallsetminus C$ has $m$ elements.